# How do I add simple delayed tasks in Django?

Tags: django, multithreading, celery, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot and need a solution to send messages to the user in the future after a specific delay. I have my system set up with Nginx, Gunicorn and Django. The idea is that if the bot needs to send the user several messages, it can delay each subsequent message by a certain amount of time before it sends it to seem more 'human'.

However, a simple `threading.Timer` approach won't work because the user might interrupt this process at any moment prompting future messages to be changed, but the timer threads might not be available to be stopped as they are on a different worker. So far I have come across two solutions:

1. Use `threading.Timer` blindly to check a to-send list in the database, can create problems with lots of unneeded threads. Also makes the database less clean/organized.
2. Use celery or some other system to execute these future tasks. Seems like overkill and over-engineering a simple problem. Tasks will always just be delayed function calls. Also a hassle dealing with which messages belong to which conversation.

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Also, a more generic question:

Ideally the best solution would be a framework where I can 'simulate' a new bot for each conversation so it acts as its own entity and holds all the state/message queue information in memory for itself. It would be necessary for this framework to only allocate resources to a bot when it needs to do something based on a preset delay or incoming message. Is there anything that exists like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use Celery for this; executing delayed function calls is its job. And I don't know why knowing what messages belong where would be more of a problem there than doing it in a thread.

But you might also want to investigate the new [Django-Channels](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) work that Andrew Godwin is doing, since that is intended to support async background tasks.

Comment: I meant dealing with canceling tasks. I would have to store the task ids somewhere (I'm guessing a database) to know which tasks to cancel for a specific conversation. Django-Channels looks cool though still a bit confusing for my use case (maybe overkill).